'parcel index.html' serves files that are different to the ones built by 'parcel build index.html'
I have a top-level await in a script.js module, which is the main module linked to my index.html. The <script> tag has type="module".
I have installed parcel locally in the project's environment. When I run npx parcel index.js, parcel creates and serves development files from the dist folder. The new .js file/s in the dist folder is linked to the new index.html as a regular script instead of a module (It doesn't have type="module". E.g. <script src="/index.f5c48570.js" defer=""></script>). Because of that, the top-level await doesn't work. I want parcel to link script.js as a module to index.html, not as a script when I run npx parcel index.html. I've tried many things, fiddled with the configurations in package.json, and read the docs but nothing seems to work.
However, when I run npx parcel build index.html, the .js file is added as a module to index.js, as expected, likely because I've set browserslist to "Chrome 80" in package.json. I want npx parcel index.html to do the same, but it doesn't.
Following is my code:
package.json (all dependencies are installed locally):
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "browserslist": "Chrome 80",
  "targets": {
    "modern": {
      "engines": {
        "browsers": "Chrome 80"
      }
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Rishi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.12.0"
  }
}


script.js:
import cloneDeep from './node_modules/lodash-es/cloneDeep.js';

const state = {
  cart: [
    { product: 'bread', quantity: 5 },
    { product: 'apples', quantity: 10 },
  ],

  user: { loggedIn: false },
};

const stateCloneDeep = cloneDeep(state);
console.log(stateCloneDeep);

const getLastPost = async function () {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const data = await res.json();

  return { title: data.at(-1).title, text: data.at(-1).body };
};

const lastPost = await getLastPost(); // Top-level await
console.log(lastPost);

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Modern JavaScript Development: Modules and Tooling</title>
  <style>
    /* ---- SOME STYLES ---- */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My Project</h1>
</body>

</html>

